# cross reference content from current word forms

Tags: microsoft-word, forms, field-codes

with the legacy word form I could insert a formtext field `{ FORMTEXT }` and show the content in a new place by using a new field `{ REF text1 \h }` where is the name text1 and which is automatically created by a cross reference of the formfield.

How could I create the same behavior with the current (non-legacy) forms from the developer tools?

Answer (score 0):

From the Properties dialog of the Content Control set a unique Style for the text entered into the Content Control. Then use a **StyleRef** field, which will repeat the referenced text.

[image]